# Someone have API soap working in VB.net?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I have tried for a while to get the Magento API via soap to work in VS2015 4.6 VB.net both web and win with no success.

I have the wsdl recognized but can't get a session id returned with login.

When using ....

```
    Dim mag1 As New mag.PortTypeClient
    Dim sessid = mag1.login("xxxxx", "xxxxxxxxx")
```

I receive the error  "Invalid XML"

Didn't know if I could correspond with someone who has been successful with this.

thanks
mark

Comment: There's an old .net wrapper for Magento's API, it may offer some insight. https://github.com/molotovbliss/csharlibformagexmlrpcapi

Answer (score 1):

Yes I have it working - I had to increase the message size and set time-out settings in order to get it functioning properly but it works.  I also found that the SoapV2 speed is very slow unless caching is turned on under general API settings in Magento.  Here is my code - Obviously you need to fill in the correct address for the endpoint and appropriate login credentials and make sure you have added the reference as a Service Reference, not a Web Reference, it does make a difference:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

'Set up endpoint binding with increased buffer / pool / quota sizes'
Dim EPAddress As EndpointAddress = New EndpointAddress("https://[magento host name]/api/v2_soap")
Dim binding As BasicHttpsBinding = New BasicHttpsBinding
binding.CloseTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 1, 0)
binding.OpenTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 1, 0)
binding.ReceiveTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 10, 0)
binding.SendTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 1, 0)
binding.AllowCookies = False
binding.BypassProxyOnLocal = False
binding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard
binding.MaxBufferSize = 20000000
binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 20000000
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 20000000
binding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text
binding.TextEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
binding.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered
binding.UseDefaultWebProxy = True

Dim Quotas As New XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas
Quotas.MaxDepth = 20000000
Quotas.MaxStringContentLength = 20000000
Quotas.MaxArrayLength = 20000000
Quotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 20000000
Quotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 20000000
binding.ReaderQuotas = Quotas

binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None
binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None
binding.Security.Transport.Realm = ""

binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName
binding.Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Default

'Create the service object using the binding settings above and appropriate end point address'
Dim ServiceClient As PortTypeClient = New PortTypeClient(binding, EPAddress)

'Make the login() call and get a Session ID'
Dim SessionID As String = ServiceClient.login("[Username]", "[APIKey]")
```

Comment: If you're having slow API calls check into autoloader class path cache, I've seen a usual reduction of response time by around 75,% just be very diligent in regression testing before using it as it rewrites a core piece, and composer needs to be considered as well. https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_ClassPathCache